# Third party driver signing

Tags: windows, driver, signing

Our software product makes use of third party USB drivers. The driver packages we get from the third party contain a mixture of `.sys` and `.dll` files, as well as a `.inf` file that references them all.

The driver manufacturers manual walks through the process of modifying the .inf file so the driver appears in the device list under our companies name rather than that of the driver manufacturer. Once we have modified the .inf file, we need to rebuild and resign the .cat file that is produced. the associated .sys and .dll files have not been modified in anyway.

Can we leave these as they are or do they need to be resigned with the same certificate that was used to sign the .cat file?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you re-build, you will have to resign the .cat file. The rest files, it doesnt matter if you leave it or re-sign, as long as you have a valid code signing certificate, since you didnt modify them.